# How can I enforce the use of a safe Guard for a limited time only?

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core

I am reading a lot of documentations and source code about Safe and its ecosystem. My goal is to use this protocol for an upcoming hackathon project.

From my understanding, a guard can be set up (and removed) by the user to add additional checks before or after a transaction. I want to know if it is possible to **enforce the use of a guard for a limited time, before allowing the user to remove it?**

I want to do that to allow people to use a feature of my project that requires a monitoring of the transactions made by the user. Basically, the user will add the guard to its Safe wallet to access the feature, and should be able to take the guard off of its wallet after a given duration (1 month for example). Is it possible to do that without modifying the existing Safe code?

My guess is that the Guard could prevent the Safe wallet itself from calling `GuardManager.setGuard()` through the `GuardManager.checkTransaction()` call made by the wallet, but for that to happens the wallet should always call `GuardManager.setGuard()` through its `Safe.execTransaction()` method. I wonder if the `FallbackManager` class could allow one to bypass the Guard checks, by adding a new fallback method that would call `GuardManager.setGuard()`?

Comment: You can include the expiry logic in the guard itself

Comment: @mikheevm You are right, I figured out that I can conditionally skip the guard checks directly in the `GuardManager.checkTransaction()` function. However, my concern is that I want the user to be **unable** to remove the guard once it is set, for a given amount of time. I guess the `GuardManager.setGuard()` function can be catched and forbidden by the Guard itself, but does the `FallbackManager` could allow the user to bypass this security?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Safe singleton contract inherits the `FallbackManager` contract, and no function can be added to the `FallbackManager` class without migrating the Safe to a new singleton. Theoretically, one could workaround the guard by adding a new module or executing a delegatecall transaction. Your guard should take this kind of transaction into account too.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is true that a new module will be able to bypass the Guard, and although I fail to understand why the modules doesn't use the Guard checks, I definitely need to take that into account. The module could either execute any logic I try to prevent, or delegatecall to `GuardManager.setGuard()` to remove my security. I will try to think of a solution around that!